# itertools combinations creates a missing pair

Tags: list, python-2.7, hash, combinations, python-itertools

I created a combination hash from an array list using the following code:

```
all_waypoints = [item1,item2,...]
waypoint_distances = {}
 for (waypoint1, waypoint2) in combinations(all_waypoints, 2):
 waypoint_distances[frozenset([waypoint1, waypoint2])] = distance
```

thereafter I go through the created combination list with this code:

```
for (waypoint1, waypoint2) in waypoint_distances.keys():
```

the problem is that half way the code the program halts and states that:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

after debugging the program I found that the waypoint_distances hash contains the following elements when the rest of my program halts:

```
...,frozenset(['an-item', 'another-item']), frozenset(['an-item']),...
```

The only thing I can think of is that the list is combination list is created uncompleted with the itertool, how can I go around this?? the problem is found around the 7050 combination hash, the total amount of combinations is about 16k.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are some duplicates in your item list, this can occur:

```
from itertools import combinations

all_waypoints = [1,2,3,1]
waypoint_distances = {}
for (waypoint1, waypoint2) in combinations(all_waypoints, 2):
    print(set([waypoint1, waypoint2]))
```

result:

```
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{1}
{2, 3}
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
```

You have to eliminate `sets` with length = 1

```
for (waypoint1, waypoint2) in combinations(all_waypoints, 2):
  fs = frozenset([waypoint1, waypoint2])
  if len(fs)==2:
     waypoint_distances[fs] = distance
```

or better: eliminate duplicates at the source with a `set`

```
for (waypoint1, waypoint2) in combinations(set(all_waypoints), 2):
```